# Embed Gfy into HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to embed an image from gfycat into my HTML but I'm having trouble.

I've tried adding this to my HTML but the image won't show up.

```
<img class="gfyitem" data-id="BlushingWeepyDartfrog" />
```

How do I embed an image from gfycat into my HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's about `<img class="gfyitem" data-id="$1" />`

Here is link http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=519533.0

I don't know exactly what u mean. but I think that link will be helped.

http://www.gfycat.com/about